# Reserved Words Where Not To Use

Tags: mysql

I made a table `(MySQL InnoDB)` with a column name `drop`. I know drop is a keyword as in '`DROP TABLE`' so was experimenting and everything is working fine.

Do I need to worry for the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to use [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). If you escape them with backticks you have no problems

```
`drop`
```

Comment: Lemme execute that SQL

Comment: Thanks juergen d, but I cant up vote for not having threshold points to up vote. Still Thanks for your time